# Design Pattern Help - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have some services which make calls for different apis, each api needs different authentication credentials but all of the services do something similar. Currently I am passing a TSetting into each service.

Base:

```
public abstract class InventoryUpdaterBase<TSetting> : IInventoryUpdaterBase<TSetting>
    {
        public abstract IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(TSetting setting);

        public abstract IEnumerable<Item> GetUpdateList(TSetting setting, IEnumerable<InventoryUpdate> inventoryUpdates);

        public abstract void Update(TSetting setting, IEnumerable<Item> items);
    }
```

ebay service here:

```
public class EbayInventoryUpdater : InventoryUpdaterBase<EbaySetting>, IEbayInventoryUpdater
    {
public override void Update(EbaySetting setting, IEnumerable<Item> items)
        {
            var ebayItems = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EbayItem>>(items);

            _fetchEbayApiService.SetCredentials(setting);
            var endpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/bulk_update_price_quantity";

            //Does something here and content generated.. not relevant

            _fetchEbayApiService.PostApi(endpoint, content);
        }
}
```

Api Service for ebay:

```
public class FetchEbayApiService : FetchApiServiceBase, IFetchEbayApiService
    {
        private EbaySetting _setting;
        public override HttpResponseMessage CallApi(string url)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            AddDefaultHeaders(httpClient);
            return httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
        }

        public override HttpResponseMessage PostApi(string url, JsonContent jsonContent)
        {
            HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"{url}");
            requestMessage.Content = jsonContent;
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            AddDefaultHeaders(httpClient);

            var response = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
            return response;
        }

        private void AddDefaultHeaders(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {_setting.AuthenticationToken}");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        }

        public void SetCredentials(EbaySetting setting)
        {
            _setting = setting;
        }
    }
```

I have tried to only give the classes I need for you to get the picture so as to not simply be pasting loads of code. Other services include WooCommerceInventoryUpdater passing in a WooSetting. I am wondering if there is a design pattern I can use to simplify this. I feel like the SetCredentials method I am going down is not a good practice.

Each setting is generated using a SettingsService passing in a userId which then fetches the settings from a database.

Table looks like

**Settings Table**

(SettingId EbaySettingId WooSettingId)

**Ebay Settings Table**

(EbaySettingId AuthToken)

**Woo Settings Table**

(WooSettingsId Secret Key)

EDIT:

```
public class CredentialsProvider : ICredentialsProvider
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public CredentialsProvider(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }



        public EbaySetting GetEbaySetting(string id)
        {
            var settings = _userRepository.GetSingle(s => s.Id == id).Setting.EbaySetting;

            return new EbaySetting()
            {
                AuthenticationToken = settings.AuthenticationToken
            };
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help!

Cheers

Comment: I am aware the base class is redundant at this point, I had future ideas for shared functionality.

Comment: I suspect this question is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your code is not much 'wrong' except that it exhibits temporal coupling due to that `SetCredentials` call. Does your `InventoryUpdater` even need the settings for purposes other than passing it further down the line to the `ApiService`? If not, then try making `SettingsProvider` or that `SettingsService` that will be injected to the `ApiService` and just use it to get the settings (instead of imperatively passing them from the outside like it is now).

Comment: @RichardDeeming thanks a lot I did not know this was a thing!!!!

Comment: And also `ApiCredentials` would be better name than `Setting`.

Comment: @Dusan that is correct settings only needed for ApiService, I see, how would I pass SettingsProvider in to that? Its an asp.net web api so how would I configure the services?

Comment: @Ben for example, register your `EbaySettingsService` as (most likely) scoped service and accept it in the constructor of the `FetchEbayApiService`. Just as you would do for like 99% of your other dependencies.

Comment: @Ben and if you are still not using dependency injection, I strongly recommend that you start using it.

Comment: @Dusan hi sorry yes of course I get what you mean, cheers for the help thats perfect!!

Comment: @Dusan hi there, just check the edit at the bottom of the post, would you pass the userId into the api service? That doesnt seem right either!!